# It seems that I am getting wrong bearer token from azure ad , APM API is unauthorized

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, asp-net-core-spa-services

```
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Constants.AUTHORITY);
            var credential =
                new ClientCredential(Constants.CLIENT_ID, Constants.CLIENT_SECRET);
            var result = (AuthenticationResult)authContext
                .AcquireTokenAsync(Constants.API_ID_URL, credential)
                .Result;
            var token = result.AccessToken;

            return token;
```

Using the above code to get bearer token, I am getting wrong / incomplete bearer token. Then adding into client header.

```
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new
 AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token); 
 HttpResponseMessage res = client.GetAsync(urlParameters).Result;  
 response is unauthorized.
```

Answer (score 0):

The token is correct. Your code looks fine too. Two possible reasons that come to mind:

- Double check that the identity you are using actually has access to the service you are trying to access.
- Make sure you are calling the api correctly. Services/endpoints have different requirements. You might get something like that if your call is incorrect, let's say you didn't provide an API version when it is required.

It would help if you provided full response body you are getting, and the full request you are making. You can obfuscate personal data.

Comment: I think I am missing authorisation setting for registered app at tenant level , I tried it but it didn’t work. Authorisation of web app at tenant level so that it can access all recourse group data .

Comment: You can use the "Check Access" feature, to see the access of your service principal.